# How to define my own primary key for a MongoDB document using Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I dont want to use `_id` as the primary key, but want to define my own key. How can I do it using mongoid given the following mongo object.

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document

end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use key with another name as primary key, then you can't do that. Every document has to have a key named `_id`, value of which will be primary key index entry.  This is how MongoDB works.

Value of `_id` field doesn't have to be an ObjectID, though. You can have whatever you like there (except for array, IIRC).

Comment: Right, the [`_id` is how MongoDB does it](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-The%5CidField) but it doesn't have to be an ObjectID (not sure what Mongoid will do with non-ObjectID `_id`s though).

Comment: Mongoid can handle non objectid ids just fine. I, for example, use strings most of the time.

Comment: If your data has a unique field (or you want to create one), and you don’t need the properties of an ObjectId, you can override the default id with your own value, just ensure uniqueness in your key.

Answer (score 1):

From the MongoDB [site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs):

"In the MongoDB shell, ObjectId() may be used to create ObjectIds.  ObjectId(string) creates an object ID from the specified hex string."

There is a code example there as well

Answer (score 1):

Sergio Tulentsev got it right, _id doesn't have to be ObjectID.

However, I'm afraid that Lynn Langit's answer may be misleading. It's true that 'ObjectId(string) creates an object ID from the specified hex string', but the string here has to be a valid ObjectID. You cannot create an ObjectID from your meaningful string.